# Не запускается java бот на удаленном сервере

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Я собрала бот, залила на удаленный сервер (beget), пытаюсь его запустить, но столкнулась с проблемой:

Я что-то не правильно прописала в настройках?
Бот на java, но на сервере он не установлен, мне надо установить?
Сборка под 20, а сервер предлагает поставить 19-ку, что делать?

Настройки для бота:

```
[unit]
Description=Telegram first bot
After=Dio

[Seervice]
SuccessExitCode=143

User=root
Group=root

Type=simple

ExecStart=java -jar /opt/bots/tg/firstbot.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

АП: теперь новая проблема после исправление первых косяков
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Command ‘java’ not found вам ни о чем не говорит? Это для начала. Я уже не говорю про unit и Seervice

Comment: Ставите jre, используя команду на экране, а потом User, Service. Полезно: https://habr.com/ru/companies/southbridge/articles/255845/

Comment: Команда Java - говорит,догадалась и поставила, а вот с остальным проблемы и лучше не молчите ,если знаете, а подскажите, Буду Вам очень признательна

Comment: Unit и Service, а не unit и Seervice

Comment: стыдно то как, а... спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить Java. Выполните команду

```
apt install default-jre
```

Затем, вместо unit и Seervice, вам надо написать Unit и Service, соответственно.

Полезно также будет свериться со статьёй по адресу https://habr.com/ru/companies/southbridge/articles/255845/

Comment: Спасибо, это сделала. Но по прежнему ошибка ExecStart. Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Дополните вопрос новыми подробностями о других ошибках.

Comment: На скрине в моем вопросе ExecStart выделен красным... ничего не поменялось в отношении этого пункта

Comment: Система не могла распознать Seervice, написанный с ошибкой. Поэтому не могла найти ExecStart. Если исправили, то теперь должна находить. Отсутствует ExecStop. Ошибка в любом случае уже должна быть иной. Со статьей сверились?

Comment: Сверилась и все исправила, помогло, но теперь новая проблема... дополнила описание

Comment: Это уже не имеет отношения к systemd. Принимайте этот, открывайте новый. У вас там проблема с правами на jar, как можно догадаться по permissions.

Comment: Там у вас firstbot или firstbot1

Comment: Это я уже потом меняла. В итоге все сработало, но запускала без ручных настроек, через screen. Все равно спасибо Вам за помощь!